# How to use regular, light and bold fonts use link from google fonts?

Tags: css, google-fonts

I need three types of Ubuntu font. I don't want to download them.

I put this link in the  tag:
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">`

In Google tutorial: "Use the following CSS rules to specify these families: font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;".

How can I use Ubuntu Light and Ubuntu bold fonts? As I see it is not the same as `font-weight: bold`; or `font-weight: 300`;.

Answer (score 4):

This is the link to use in the `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

within your CSS file use:

```
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
```

and

```
font-weight: 300
```

Comment: @dmytro-litovskyi - If this is correct please mark as a correct answer please

Comment: @dmytro-litovskyi - If this is correct please mark as a correct answer please

Comment: Hey please can you accept this answer as the correct one please, it has 4 upvotes and answers your question - thank you

Answer (score 1):

font-weight 300 is equivalent of light,
400 is regular and 500 is medium.
you should add light and medium fonts to your link like as

link to google font:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

css:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 }
.light {
  font-weight:300; 
 }
.regular{
  font-weight:400; 
}

.medium{
  font-weight:500; 
   }
```

working code: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/bxyEdK